# MVC5 LogOff and ReturnToAction not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following method that I know is being hit as I attached the debugger to it.

```
 [HttpPost]
 [AllowAnonymous]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 Public ActionResult LogOff()
 {
     AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
     return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account", null);
 }
```

the Sign Out is working, but the Redirect To Action does nothing. the user is definitely logged off as if I click on any button on my site, it takes me back to the log in page. So its as though the return RedirectToAction() is not executing.
Looking at the Response in the Browser, all that is being sent back is /Account/Login.

So what do I need to change to get this to work, or should I not be using ReturnToAction at all?

Comment: Why you use 'routeValues' as null. Have you tried using - return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");

Comment: The null was already there. that is basically a boilerplate method from the site template. Removing it makes no difference.

Comment: Try removing decorated attributes as this isn't any post action isn't it. [HttpPost]
 [AllowAnonymous]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] Also check whats on your owin startup  section, and compare with MVC5 normal template.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Redirect** method:

```
return Redirect("~/Account/Login");
```

OR

Define this route in **RouteConfig.cs**

```
routes.MapRoute(
 "MyRoute", // Route name
 "Account/", // URL 
 new { controller = "Account", action = "Login"} // Parameter defaults
 );
```

Comment: That makes no difference. the URl doesn't change. But if you hit Logoff, see the code hit the LogOut method, then hit he log off  buttong again, nothing happens. In Fact, stepping through the code, I can see the Login Page being rendered in teh code. It just seems that it is never sent back to the Browser